# How to sort integers in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.3

> Please note that this is on Python 3.3

**Here is the code:**

```
students=int(input("How many student's score do you want to sort? "))
options=input("What do you want to sort: [Names with scores] , [Scores high to low] , [Scores averages] ? ")
options=options.upper()

if options == ("NAMES WITH SCORES") or  options == ("NAME WITH SCORE") or  options == ("NAME WITH SCORES") or options == ("NAMES WITH SCORE"):
    a=[]
    for i in range(0,students):
        name=input("Enter your scores and name: ")
        a.append(name)

    a.sort()
    print("Here are the students scores listed alphabetically")
    print(a)

if options == ("SCORES HIGH TO LOW") or  options == ("SCORE HIGH TO LOW"):
    b=[]
    number=0
    for i in range(0,students):
        number = number+1
        print("Student "+str(number))
        name2=int(input("Enter your first score: "))
        name3=int(input("Enter your second score: "))
        name4=int(input("Enter your third score: "))

        b.append(name2)
        b.append(name3)
        b.append(name4)

    final_score = name2 + name3 + name4
    print (final_score)
    b.sort(final_score)
    print("Student "+str(number) )
    print(b)
```

**Here is the outcome of the code:**

```
>>> 
How many student's score do you want to sort? 2
What do you want to sort: [Names with scores] , [Scores high to low] , [Scores averages] ? scores high to low
Student 1
Enter your first score: 1
Enter your second score: 2
Enter your third score: 3
Student 2
Enter your first score: 3
Enter your second score: 5
Enter your third score: 6
14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\GCSE Computing\Task 3\Task 3.py", line 31, in <module>
    b.sort(final_score)
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function
>>>
```

I want the code to add the three scores of the students and sort the total scores of the students, with the according name.

For example:
(2 Students)

**Student 1**

- Score 1 - 2
- Score 2 - 4
- Score 3 - 7

*(Therefore the total is 13)*

**Student 2**

- Score 1 - 5
- Score 2 - 1
- Score 3 - 4

*(Therefore the total is 10)*

*(The program prints in order from highest to lowest)*

"Student 1 - 15 , Student 2 - 10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the syntax `key=final_score` when passing a function to sort by:

`b.sort(key=final_score)`

But the sort method expects a  `function` to be passed in **not** a variable so passing the `int` value from adding `name2 + name3 + name4` is not going to work.

If you just want the list of scores sorted simply call `b.sort()`

What you should be doing is using a defautdict and using each name as key and store all scores in a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict


d = defaultdict(list)

for _ in range(students):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    scores = input("Enter your scores separated by a space: "
    # add all scores for the user to the list
    d[name].extend(map(int,scores.split()))
```

To show mean, total and max it is trivial:

```
# from statistics import mean will work for python 3.4

for k,v in d.items():
       print("Scores total for {} is {}".format(k,sum(v)))
       print("Scores average for {} is {}".format(k,sum(v)/len(v))) # mean(v) for python 3,4
       print("Highest score  for {} is {}".format(k, max(v)))
```

Print sorted by highest user total score:

```
print("The top scoring students from highest to lowest are:")
for k,v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:sum(x[1]),reverse=True):
    print("{} : {}".format(k,sum(v)))
```

Now you have a dict where the student names are the keys and each students scores are all stored in a list.

Really you should add a try/except taking the user input and verify it is in the correct format.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. Here is the outcome:

Comment: How many student's score do you want to sort? 2
What do you want to sort: [Names with scores] , [Scores high to low] , [Scores averages] ? scores high to low
What is your name? test
Enter your first score: 1
Enter your second score: 2
Enter your third score: 3
What is your nametest 2
Enter your first score: 3
Enter your second score: 4
Enter your third score: 5
12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\GCSE Computing\Task 3\Task 3.py", line 31, in <module>
    b.sort(key = final_score)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>

Comment: @ThifyanRavinehru, yes you need to pass a function as the key, how can python sort using an int?

Comment: So, it is not possible to do what I wanted  to do (sorting int variables) ?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without variables, because I just want the 3 scores to add up and the total to be sorted.

Comment: no `final_score = name2 + name3 + name4` is an int how could you sort just one number?

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll do enter your total score. Thank you for your help, I will just wait a bit to check if anyone else knows a different way. If not, I will vote yours as best answer.

Comment: I added a way to simply store all names and all their scores. All you have to do is sum the list values to get total scores and sort to get the highest

Comment: 'if options == ("SCORES HIGH TO LOW") or  options == ("SCORE HIGH TO LOW"):

    from collections import defaultdict

    d = defaultdict(list)

    for _ in range(students):
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        scores = input("Enter your scores separated by a space: "
        # add all scores for the user to the list
        d[name].extend(map(int,scores.split()))
    # from statistics import mean will work for python 3.4

Comment: for k,v in d.items():
           print("Scores total for {} is {}".format(k,sum(v)))
           print("Scores average for {} is {}".format(k,sum(v)/len(v))) # mean(v) for python 3,4
           print("Highest score  for {} is {}".format(k, max(v)))

Comment: it says invalid syntax and highlights the b from 'b[name]'

Comment: sorry i didn't know about the code format here is my code:

Comment: `if options == ("SCORES HIGH TO LOW") or  options == ("SCORE HIGH TO LOW"):

    from collections import defaultdict

    d = defaultdict(list)

    for _ in range(students):
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        scores = input("Enter your scores separated by a space: "
        # add all scores for the user to the list
        d[name].extend(map(int,scores.split()))
    # from statistics import mean will work for python 3.4`

Comment: `for k,v in d.items():
           print("Scores total for {} is {}".format(k,sum(v)))
           print("Scores average for {} is {}".format(k,sum(v)/len(v))) # mean(v) for python 3,4
           print("Highest score  for {} is {}".format(k, max(v)))`

Comment: I know why I was getting the error, its because there wasn't  a closed bracket after:

Comment: `scores = input("Enter your scores separated by a space: "`

Thank you very much for the help Padraic